# Entity Framework with Big Database

Tags: entity-framework, enterprise-library

I just want to ask if I can use the Entity Framework for an enterprise application where database size can be 150+ tables and can be 100+ transactions per second.

We have very detailed reporting requirements with complete ordering Audit Log requirements.

I am bit confused if I should use Entity Framework or if I should go with Enterprise Library Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can use. actually it depends on trick you use in your data access or repository layer. memory handling is so important subject when you are using an ORM.
for example using linq instead of navigation property in complex joins and using IEnumerable or IQuerable based on your needs(hope you know enough about that).
try to use Entity framework 5 or 6 and code first approach as Ef supports UnitOfWork Pattern by default and you don't need to write your own Unit Of Work pattern anymore.
get [this](https://github.com/elbandit/Asp-Net-Design-Patterns) project and take a look at repository layer with Entity Framework, it's the best implementation I've ever seen for enterprise application and used it several time for big enterprise applications.